# How to rename actual portable HDD *device* name? (not volume name / label)

Tags: windows, usb, external-hard-drive, rename

I have a few Toshiba Stor.E drives connected to my pc for backup purposes, then shipping them to differen physical locations.

But when working with a few of them I have to check many times if I use the correct drives, not all software shows the serials.

For example, Windows Task Manager:
[image]

[image]

As can be seen, both devices are identified with the same name "TOSHIBA External USB 3.0 USB Device".

My question is: How can I change that, not only for the current PC, but for all PC's these drive will be connected to? EG "TOSHIBA External USB 3.0 USB Device 1" and "TOSHIBA External USB 3.0 USB Device 2" would be good names to distinguish them.

How can I do this from Windows 8?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know device name cannot be changed. It is device/model specific. However if you are looking for easy way to identify the actual storage device you can look at partition labels. These can be changed easily and will show in explorer program on your and any other PC. You can use any partitioning program to change labels. As far as I know under windows you can change the label directly from explorer by renaming the storage disk.
I hope that helps

Comment: That is true, but most of the disk I connect are unpartitioned in the first place..

Comment: Well, you don't expect them to be different on the very same moment when you connect them, do you?

Comment: Yeah but all disk names are also the same (backups, exact one:one copies) after cloning, no drive letters.

Comment: Well, then don't be shy and rename it, isn't this what you want?